# add two lists and an image as a header of an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have two lists which have dynamic patient data in an excel workbook. So each worksheet is assigned to a patient. I want to add header in the excel so that when I print this workbook, on each page while printing this header should be displayed. As shown in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ykrV.png), I want the header part 1#, header part 2# and logo to be the header. How can I do this in python using xlsxwriter?
[image: RequiredHeader]

I had this code but if the user enters long texts in one of the field it moves the static header that i created.

```
    def write_header(self, index):
        first_index_copy = index
        # name
        if type(self.client['full_name'].unique()[0]) == str:
            full_name = self.client['full_name'].unique()[0]
        else:
            full_name = ''
        # birthday
        if type(self.client['birthday'].unique()[0]) == str:
            birthday = self.client['birthday'].unique()[0]
        else:
            birthday = ''
        # date of the log
        date_today = str(datetime.today().month) + "/" + str(datetime.today().year)
        # allergies
        allergies_str = ', '.join([elem for elem in self.client.allergy.unique() if str(elem) != 'nan'])
        header_list_part1 = self.map_dict.map_header(full_name, birthday, date_today, allergies_str)

        for i, line in enumerate(header_list_part1):
            self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 0, line[0], self.mars.bold_border)
            self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 1, line[1], self.mars.bold_border)
            index += 1

        header_list_part2 = self.map_dict.header_list_part2

        index += 2
        for i, elem in enumerate(header_list_part2):
            if i == len(header_list_part2) - 1:
                self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 0, elem, self.mars.bold)
            else:
                self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 0, elem)
            index += 1
        index = self.write_first_grid(index)
        self.mars.worksheet.insert_image('D'+str(first_index_copy+1), 'logo.jpg')

        return index
```

I also tried this code which prints my required header at just the top of each worksheet but when i print it gives it only at one place and does not come on all printed pages of that sheet which i understand is because if the `write` function that I have used instead of `set_header` and therefore my header is just treated as normal text and not header:

```
    def test_header(self, index):
        # name
        first_index_copy = index
        if type(self.client['full_name'].unique()[0]) == str:
            full_name = self.client['full_name'].unique()[0]
        else:
            full_name = ''
        # birthday
        if type(self.client['birthday'].unique()[0]) == str:
            birthday = self.client['birthday'].unique()[0]
        else:
            birthday = ''
        # date of the log
        date_today = str(datetime.today().month) + "/" + str(datetime.today().year)
        # allergies
        allergies_str = ', '.join([elem for elem in self.client.allergy.unique() if str(elem) != 'nan'])
        header_list_part1 = self.map_dict.map_header(full_name, birthday, date_today, allergies_str)
        for i, line in enumerate(header_list_part1):
            self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 0, line[0], self.mars.bold_border)
            self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 1, line[1], self.mars.bold_border)
            index += 1
        header_list_part2 = self.map_dict.header_list_part2

        index += 2
        for i, elem in enumerate(header_list_part2):
            if i == len(header_list_part2) - 1:
                self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 0, elem, self.mars.bold)
            else:
                self.mars.worksheet.write(index, 0, elem)
            index += 1
        index = self.write_first_grid(index)
        self.mars.worksheet.insert_image('D' + str(first_index_copy + 1),
                                         'logo.jpg')
```

Can you help me define it as a header so that I see this on each printable page?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this in the following way:

```
    def test_header(self):
        # name
        if type(self.client['full_name'].unique()[0]) == str:
            full_name = self.client['full_name'].unique()[0]
        else:
            full_name = ''
        # birthday
        if type(self.client['birthday'].unique()[0]) == str:
            birthday = self.client['birthday'].unique()[0]
        else:
            birthday = ''
        # date of the log
        date_today = str(datetime.today().month) + "/" + str(datetime.today().year)
        # allergies
        allergies_str = ', '.join([elem for elem in self.client.allergy.unique() if str(elem) != 'nan'])
        # creating patient info
        patient_data = 'Patient: ' + full_name +\
                       '\nDate of Birth: ' + birthday +\
                       '\nMonth/Year: ' + date_today +\
                       '\nAllergies: ' + allergies_str

        # creating header text which contains patient data and tenant image
        header_text = '&L&14&"Calibri,Bold"{}&R&G'.format(patient_data)
        self.mars.worksheet.set_header(header_text, {'image_right': 'logo.png'})
```

I hope it is useful!